# Optional Parameters in C# at Sharepoint

Tags: development, asp.net

How Could I set optional parameters when programing in sharepoint. Now I'm while debuging getting error:

`Feature 'optional parameter' cannot be used because it is not part of the 3.0 C# language specification`

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In VS2010, you can use optional parameters with .NET 3.5.
See [this link](http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2013/07/feature-optional-parameter-cannot-be.html) for solution.

> Right Click on the project
>
> Go to properties
>
> Go to Build Tab
>
> Click on ‘Andvanced’
>
> Set language version to ‘default’
>   Save the project

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters are C# 4.0 language feature and not 3.0. Moreover, SharePoint development is not done in 4.0 but in 3.5

Comment: I kcow, but how could I use them in Sharepoint ? I couldn't ?